# How to run while loop maximum 5 times in php

Tags: php, while-loop

I have total 10 post but i want to run while loop only 5 times. and want to show only 5 values. I am very new in wordpress/php so any kind of help would be really appreciated :)

Here is my code :

```
<?php query_posts('page_id=4');
                    $i=0;
                    ?> 
                   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

if( have_rows('numbers_area') ): while ( have_rows('numbers_area') ) : the_row();
                if( get_row_layout() == 'numbers_area' ):

                    ?> 

                    <div class="col-md-2 <?php if ($i==0){ ?> col-md-offset-1 <?php } ?> col-sm-6">
                        <div class="facts_information facts_information_1">
                            <h5><span class="count"><?php echo get_sub_field('numbers'); ?></span></h5>
                            <p><?php echo get_sub_field('details'); ?></p>
                            <i class="<?php echo get_sub_field('icon'); ?>" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <?php

                    $i++;

              endif;
          endwhile;
        endif;
          endwhile;
        ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried in order to get the desired functionality?

Comment: This looks similar to your other question related to <li>.. iterator should work here too

Comment: Please don't abuse tags. [tag:wordpress] has nothing to do with the question. If you want a solution in wordpress style, please reword the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if($i>=5){break;}
//other code
```

this work for sure..

Comment: Thanks Bro it's Working :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  query_posts('page_id=4'); 
  $count = 0; 
  while (have_posts()):
      the_post();  
      $count=$count+1;
      if(count == 5 )
          break;
      endif;
  endwhile;
?>
```